# Locating the outer boundary of the iris

Tags: image-processing, matlab, filters

I need help with iris localization. I have applied the `imfincircle` function to locate it, but it only locates the inner boundary of the pupil and does not find outer boundary.

How do I locate the outer boundary?

Answer (score 1):

Hough transform is an edge based operation. For this reason, if you could extract the edges of the outer boundary (together with many noisy pixels) and adjust the radius parameter of the Hough transform, you will be finding the circle of the iris, but not anywhere else. You might want to check:

```
[centers,radii] = imfindcircles(A,radiusRange)
```

`radiusRange` is the parameter you should get right.

However, sometimes for some noisy images, Circular Hough Transform might not be the solution. In such cases you might try Hough ellipses or other methods for locating geometric primitives.

Comment: how to perform iris normalization ? what are the approaches for Normailization ?

Comment: Please do not cross post: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13913/how-to-do-iris-normalization