# How to perform iris normalization?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I have done with [iris localization](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13100/locating-the-outer-boundary-of-the-iris). Now I need to perform iris normalization, but I don't have any idea about it. How to implement iris normalization please?

Comment: see this younger jour. and search for it: http://ijceit.org

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following for Iris Normalization:

> [Nithyanandam. S, Gayathri K.S., Priyadarshini P.L.K. - *A New IRIS Normalization Process For The Recognition System With Cryptographic Techniques*](http://ijcsi.org/papers/IJCSI-8-4-1-342-348.pdf)
>
> [Arvacheh E. - *A Study of Segmentation and Normalization for Iris
>   Recognition
>   Systems*](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/2846/emohamma2006.pdf?sequence=1)

Comment: is there any builtin method for nomalization ?

Comment: Built-in to what? There are several open source solutions available though.

Answer (score -1):

you can also this two papers for iris and normalization:

S Zeriouh, M Boutahri, SE Yamani, A Roukhe. "[Contribution of Artificial Neural Networks to the Identification and Detection of Targets Concerning Mobility on Remote Sensing Images.](http://ijcsse.org/published/volume4/issue5/p4-V4I5.pdf)" International Journal of Computer Science and Software Engineering 4, no. 5 (2015): 130-136.

How to implement iris normalization?

R Safdari, Z Azadmanjir. "[Wireless Networks in Hospitals; a Framework of Use and Implementation for Nursing Care.](http://www.ijcncs.org/published/volume2/issue6/p1_2-6.pdf)" International Journal of Computer Networks and Communications Security 2, no. 6 (2015): 188-196.

Comment: Lovely, thank you for your answer. But could you provide explanation of the methods and what are the advantages/disadvantages and theory behind them?